# PyCharm autocomplete slow

Tags: performance, autocomplete, pycharm

Autocomplete is slow for some python modules, for example for numpy:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcAjEElSUCc

It usually takes a second or two for autocomplete to start showing possible autocomplete options. I set autopopup delay to 0 ms, but this did not help.

I use Ubuntu 15.10. I have 8 core AMD processor and 32 gb of ram. 
Same autocompletion in LiClipse on my machine is instantaneous.

I usually use heavily autocomplete, thus for me speed matters. I would greatly appreciate if someone would help me to make autocomplete faster or to let me know that it is not possible.

Comment: Have you reported it as a bug?

Comment: Probably related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21180

Comment: Has this problem been solved in the latest updates, or do you still feel that the process is rather slow?